# How can I get a polyhedron to fill in faces properly in OpenSCAD?

Tags: 3d-modelling, 3d-model, openscad

I'm new to OpenSCAD. I'm trying to create a basic triangular wedge which is going to be part of a larger component. But I'm already running into trouble. Using the following code I get the points in the correct spots; however, it seems the faces are kind of "bent inward." In other words the faces of the polyhedron don't fill in all the way.

```
polyhedron(
    points = [
        [-0.3, 0.15, 0],
        [-0.4, 0.15, 0],
        [-0.3, 0.6, 0],
        [-0.4, 0.6, 0],
        [-0.3, 0.15, -0.7],
        [-0.4, 0.15, -0.7]
    ],
    faces = [
        [0,1,2,3],
        [2,3,4,5],
        [1,3,5],
        [0,2,4],
        [0,1,4,5]
    ]
);
```

Here are some screenshots from different angles to illustrate what I mean by "bent inward":

[image: angle #1]
[image: angle #2]
[image: angle #3]

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look here: [openscad documentation polyhedron](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/The_OpenSCAD_Language#polyhedron)

> Point ordering for faces When looking at the face from the outside inwards, the points must be clockwise.

[you can highlight wrong oreintated faces](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/The_OpenSCAD_Language#polyhedron_-_polygon_orientation_issues)

correct faces e.g.:

```
faces = [
        [1,3,2,0],
        [2,3,5,4],
        [1,5,3],
        [0,2,4],
        [0,4,5,1]
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can disregard the clockwise orientation requirment if you break up the rectangle areas into 2 triangles.

```
polyhedron(
    points = [
        [-0.3, 0.15, 0],
        [-0.4, 0.15, 0],
        [-0.3, 0.6, 0],
        [-0.4, 0.6, 0],
        [-0.3, 0.15, -0.7],
        [-0.4, 0.15, -0.7]
    ],
    faces = [
        [0,1,2], [1,2,3], //break into 2 triangles
        [2,3,4], [3,4,5], //break into 2 triangles
        [1,3,5],
        [0,2,4],
        [0,1,4 ], [1,4,5] //break into 2 triangles
    ]
);
```

[image]